# rails 4: find by includes field

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails 3 I had this query:

```
Supporter.includes(:person).where("concat(club_member_number, ' ', people.surname, ' ',  people.name) LIKE ?", term)
```

However in Rails 4 it througth an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'person.surname'
```

How I could change the query for it work in Rails 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following

```
Supporter.eager_load(:person).where("concat(club_member_number, ' ', people.surname, ' ',  people.name) LIKE ?", term)
```

OR use `references(:person)` with `includes`

```
Supporter.includes(:person).where("concat(club_member_number, ' ', people.surname, ' ',  people.name) LIKE ?", term).references(:person)
```

Refer [this](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/)